# What are the advantages of using Azure File Sync over azcopy sync to migrate local data to Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, storage, azure-blob-storage

I have to choose the best tool to migrate data from on-premises to Azure.
Ideal solution would enable to sync the on-prem filesystem to an Azure storage account allowing for “differential sync” or (delta sync) for handling large files incremental updates.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [Features and Benefits](https://www.crn.in/thought-leader/benefits-of-azure-files-and-azure-file-sync/) of using Azure File Sync:

1. Multiple File Servers at multiple locations. Sync all to single Azure File Storage. Commonly used files are cached on local server . If local server goes down, quickly install another Server or VM and sync Azure files to it.
2. The older , rarely accessed files will move to Azure thus freeing your local file Server .
3. Sync Group helps to manage locations that should be kept in sync with each other. Every Sync Group has one common Cloud Storage. So a Sync Group will have one Azure End point and multiple Server end points. There is a 2 way sync so that changes to Cloud are replicated on local server within 12 to 24 hours. But changes on a local server are replicated to all end points within 5 minutes.
4. An agent is installed on the Server end point . There is no need to change or relocate data on a different volume. Thus it is non-disruptive type of agent.
5. Every Server end point creates an Azure file share in the storage account. End user experience is unchanged.
6. When a particular local file is getting synced , then it is locked. But this is only for a few seconds.
7. A Disaster Recovery Solution for File Server. If local File Server is destroyed, set up a VM or physical server , join to the previous sync group and you get “rapid restore”.
8. When a file is renamed or moved, the meta data is preserved.
9. Its different from One Drive . One Drive is for Personal Document management and is not a general purpose File Server. One Drive is primarily meant for collaborating on Office files. Not optimized for very large files , CAD drawings, multimedia development projects.
10. Azure File Sync works with On Premise AD and not Azure AD.